# Android Parsing XML file get specific data

Tags: android, xml, kotlin

I have an android code written in Kotlin to get xml data from xml file

```
data.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <questions>

        <question>aaa</question>
        <question>bbb</question>
        <question>ccc</question>


    </questions>


</resources>
```

Kotlin Code which will read the xml file above:

```
        val _is = resources.openRawResource(+R.xml.data)
        val reader = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(_is))
        val data = StringBuffer()
        var line = reader.readLine()
        while (line != null) {
            data.append(line!! + "\n")
            line = reader.readLine()
        }
        val resourceData = (data.toString())
```

I tried to print the value of resourceData  and i got this

```
�������������l��������������������������4����������������������������������������������)������aaa��bbb��ccc��question��      questions��     resources�������������������$������������������������������������������������$������������������������������������������������$����������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������$��������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������$��������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������
```

How I can only get the data i want depended on the tag ?
and is it good way to parse a xml file ?

Comment: Are you trying to read it like a text file or parse it?

Comment: Please call openRawResource to open raw file R.raw.* (res/raw/*) only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably should use XmlResourceParser [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/XmlResourceParser)

you can get its instance for xml placed in res/xml folder like this:

```
val xmlResourceParser: XmlResourceParser = resources.getXml(R.xml.your_xml_file_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're treating an xml file like a raw file, by using `openRawResource()`:

```
val _is = resources.openRawResource(+R.xml.data)
```

if you only wanted to read the lines of the file (which I doubt) you should have put it in `raw` folder and use this:

```
val _is = resources.openRawResource(R.raw.data)
```

but if you need to parse it like an xml then read this:  
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/XmlResourceParser  
finally if you just want the values inside the file then you could create a string array inside `strings.xml` like this:

```
<string-array name="questions">
    <item>aaa</item>
    <item>bbb</item>
    <item>ccc</item>
</string-array>
```

and get it in your activity:

```
val questions = resources.getStringArray(R.string.questions)
```

now questions is an array of all the values you need.